# jQuery animate next div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to animate the div within an list item with a click event but can't see why the code isn’t working?

It works when I specify the direct path to the div but I want to keep the script so it does'nt use specific classes.

```
$('#home ul.circles li').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1500 );
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="circles">
        <li class="c-1"><div class="c-1-active">Text Link</div></li>
        <li class="c-2"></li>
        <li class="c-3"></li>                             
</ul>
```

I'm trying to reverse the effect but can't seem to store the path to a var?

```
$('#home ul.circles li').click(function() {
    alert(testing);
    if(testing > "" || testing == $(this).find('div'))
    {
        testing.animate({opacity: 0, top:'180px'}, 1000 );
    }
        $(this).find('div').animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1000 );
        var testing = $(this).find('div');

});
```

Comment: so if c-1 gets clicked, what div is gonna get animated? there are no "next" divs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div is inside the li element. Use `.find(..)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$(this).next('div').animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1500 );
```

With:

```
$(this).parent().find('div').animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1500 );
```

Or:

```
$(this).find('div').animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1500 );
```

Depends on what you want to achieve.

div isn't a sibling of any of the `li` but a child of one of them.

Comment: I'm goint to want to reverse the animation but having issues storing the path to the active state. I'll add code to orignal post.

Answer (score 0):

There can be lot of problems like -

- You haven't kept your code inside $(document).ready(fn);
- The element (div) that you are trying to animate doesn't have position: relative or absolute on it.
- You can also experiment putting some initial opacity for the div.

A jsfiddle link is created, hope it helps. 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myHC4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use '>' in the selector, to select direct children of the li element. This will only select the div. Is there is another div inside the div, it will not be selected:

```
$('#home ul.circles li').click(function() {
    $(this).find('>div').animate({opacity: 0.2, top:'0'}, 1500 );
});​​​​​​​​​​​
```